# How to use url.build in JS?

Tags: magento2, javascript

I am getting

```
Uncaught TypeError: url.build is not a function
```

I need to use ajax in JS to get the controller method on the checkout page on click of place order.

This is my JS file

```
require(['jquery', 'mage/url'], function( url ){
            console.log( url );
});
```

How can i use url.build function to get the baseurl in js file.
Does anyone know how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you flush cache after change js code?

Answer (score 1):

Your url parameter reference to the jQuery js instead of mage/url so you have to just change like below:

```
        require(['jquery', 'mage/url'], function($, url ){


               console.log( url );

               });
```

Comment: I've the exact code. but still the same error.

`require([ 'jquery',  'mage/url'], function( $, url ){
 
  geturl = url.build('/module_name/Index/getPrice') ;
  
    console.log( geturl );
 
}); `

Error :-
`Uncaught TypeError: url.build is not a function`

Comment: Any idea 
why url.build is not working in my custom module?
Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you run php bin/magento se:up ?

Comment: yes, i run  
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
command each time I update my code. but I am not getting the url, build in my js

Comment: setup:upgrade command has nothing to do with it. that only checks the module and version and dothe needfull for the database, simple cache flush or in worst case removing pub/static/* content should work for you !

Answer (score 1):

```
require(['jquery', 'mage/url'], function ($, url) { 
    var myUrl = url.build('frontname/controllerfolder/controllername');
    console.log(myUrl);
});
```

Comment: It says 
` Uncaught TypeError: url.build is not a function
    at iostpay_func.js:3`